# How to downgrade from Visual Fox Pro 9 to Visual Fox Pro 6 (VFP6)?

Tags: windows-8, visual-foxpro

I need to downgrade from Visual FoxPro 9 to 6.

I have a working installation of VFP9 and according to this site: http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~VFP6RuntimeFiles I need 3 libraries(vfp6r.dll, vfp6renu.dll, vfp6t.dll), which I have added to the VFP 9 installation path (same path where the .exe application for starting VFP 9 is).

Still, after doing this, when I run the exe file, version 9 opens. How exactly can I downgrade to Fox Pro 6?

Maybe I need to add something to the register after copying those 3 dlls? Maybe I should remove some dlls from the existing installation? Appreciate all your help. Thank you! I have Windows 8.

Comment: You must actually install Visual FoxPro 6 in order to run Visual FoxPro 6.  You will be unable to run Visual FoxPro 6 with just those 3 DLLs.

Comment: That's what I did, eventually. I was able to find Visual FoxPro 6 after long searches. There was no way I could downgrade from FoxPro 9, in spite of all the articles about copying and overriding dlls... which certainly doesn't mean it isn't possible, but at least I didn't succeed and had to go about it in a cleaner/straight way. Thank you.